# solrj error when trying to use java.util.Set

Tags: java, solrj, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.0

I am trying to run a solr query using solrj against a cassandra table that has a collection that is a `java.util.Set`.

When my results come back I get an exception when trying to use the `getBeans` method of the solr document:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.Set field com.mycompany.entities.MyEntity.groupId to java.util.ArrayList
```

Basic query code:

```
 QueryResponse results = getSolrServer().query(query);
 SolrDocumentList documentList = results.getResults();
 List<MyEntity> results = results.getBeans(MyEntity.class);
```

My entity:

```
public class MyEntity{
     @Field
     Set<String> groupId;
}
```

Has anyone had success using a `Set` and storing it to be retrieved through solr and if so how have you got it to work with solrj?

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix. I ended up using a separate setter that took in a list and put the annotation for @Field on that setter